# German Umlaut problem - packages fontenc/inputenc do not work properly for included documents

Tags: include, input-encodings, font-encodings

I have a project with (so far) 5 included files. Within the first and the last included file the Umlauts are properly displayed, in the other three files there are undefined symbols in the output. 
Fot the title page everything is fine also, the umlaut ü is preperly transferred to ü in the pdf.

%%%%%%%%%\include{Kap1}) - I do not know how to include a minimal sample of an included document in a master document, so I addedb%%%%%%%%%\include{Kap1} to show you how i included, similarly to the other four files... perhaps this is hint enough?

The umplauts are not properly displayed in my output pdf as long as I don't use e. g. \"a which is of course possible put really time consuming while writing a document which should finally consist of 200 pages. And, however, in 2 of 5 files i do not need those \"...

Do I need to use the inputenc and fontenc command AGAIN in the included documents?

Thanks in advance for your answers! And sorry for the uncoloured code - i do not know how to colour it.
Lisa

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}%[ansinew]für eurozeichen; [latin9][UTF8] entfernt helfen ebenfalls nicht 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %für Umlautdarstellung
\usepackage{textcomp} %zur Behebung weiterer Umlautfehler, Extrasymbole

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{setspace}% erlaubt Befehle: singlespacing, onehalfspacing und doublespacing
\onehalfspacing

%%********** ENDE PRÄAMBEL************

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 \begin{center}
{\Large Lisa Müller}
 \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
%%

%%%%%%%%%\include{Kap1} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you check all included files have the same input encoding?

Comment: Please verify for each if your documents that they are all written in the same encoding.  Are you 100% sure you are using ansinew? Most editors today use utf8. Many of them will even tell you which encoding withe current file is using (texmaker and texstudio are good at that).

Comment: at least `ansinew` doesn't work in my installation but `utf8` does. Additional, you could try to use `lmodern` for the eurosymbol. (and have a look at you `tex`-files are the saved in `utf8`? `TeXStudio` shows the encoding of the shown `tex`-file in the bottom menu but you could also check it in most text editors like `notepad++` )

Comment: `lmodern` doesn't only have an ok euro symbol, it has a better support of umlaute and sonderzeichen in general. Because it's basically an updated version of computern modern (the standard font of LaTeX, some people may prefer a different choice of words) the math fonts of the `ams`-package etc match latin modern as good as the match computer modern. (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodern/)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! So fast :) How do I check the encoding? Im pretty sure that you identified the problem. Copying the the text of the 3 "broken" files and including into the 2 "working" helped my problem.

Comment: Please tell us which editor do you use. Then we can tell were you can check the encoding (TeXnicCenter and TeXworks shows the coding in the bottom line of the window).

Comment: Since you seem to speak German, check out [TeXwelt: Wie überprüfe ich die Standardeingabekodierung in meinem Editor?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2656/wie-uberprufe-ich-die-standardeingabekodierung-in-meinem-editor) for help on finding out the encoding in your editor.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is the texniccenter (although i used winedt for a while in between, and i think that caused the problem). I checked now and you were right, the files that were "correct" corresponding with fontenc and inputenc were "ANSI"-coded, UTF-8 was the one that didn't. I suppose the [UTF-8]-fontenc would have worked there. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are two points where you have the control over the file encoding:

1. for example for `pdflatex`: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
2. for TeXnicCenter (and other editors): define with which encoding the TeX file has to be saved on the hard disk.

BTW: The encoding UTF-8 is in my opinion the best choice, then you can exchange files between different operating systems usually with no problems.

**Both choices for the encoding has to be the same!**

The following images shows the way you can check and change the encoding with TeXnicCenter:

[image]

In the bottom line of TeXnicCenter (see small red circle) you can see the encoding the file has at the moment you opened it.

If you want to change the encoding, click on "File" -- "Save as". Then you can change the encoding (see big red circle).